# Sonarqube 7.7 doesn't start when I use sonar.web.context

Tags: sonarqube

I downloaded the latest version of Sonarqube to try the new capabilities and it worked well. I have developed some custom pages and they use the context to build some urls. My problem is that when I configured the Sonarqube property to add a context, the server would not start.

I work on Windows 7, with a Mysql 5.6 database.

The error message indicates that the access is denied because the port is already taken but it is not. When I remove the sonar context property, everything works fine.

Here is the console logs:

> $ StartSonar.bat
>
> wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
>
> wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
>
> jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
>
> jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>
> jvm 1    |
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:40:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\temp
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:40:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9006
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:40:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\temp\es6 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\logs\es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:40:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:40:07 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:40:07 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin] jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:40:56 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:40:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\g588969\Desktop\sonarqube-7.7\temp\sq-process7642152837509776053properties
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49981, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49977, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49984, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49982, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49987, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49986, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:50093, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49985, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49983, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49976, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49980, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49978, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    | 2019.06.21 16:41:05 WARN  app[][o.e.t.TcpTransport] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:49988, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9006}], closing connection
>
> jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
>
> jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
>
> jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

[Edit]:
Here is the configuration with the context:

```
# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
sonar.web.context=mycontext
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
sonar.web.port=9005
```

Comment: " My problem is that when I configured the Sonarqube property to add a context, the server would not start.": You should show us that part in order to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found the solution and it worked for me

What you have to do is just go to C:\sonarqube directory path\sonarqube-8.0\conf
and change `sonar.web.port=9000` to `sonar.web.port=9004`

and as well as `sonar.search.port=9001` to any other port number like `sonar.search.port=9009`

and save the changed file . Then try to start again and your Sonarqube will run as required.

This issue occurs because your port that you mentioned for Sonarqube has occupied by the other process in OS.